# Meaning of "goodies"

Tags: single-word-requests, internet

I see the word *goodies* being used widely on the internet, but I can't construe its meaning clearly. Could you explain it thoroughly?

Comment: Goodies can be looked up [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/goodies?s=t). Mostly it's used to refer to food, such as titbits. It could also refer to the "goodies", as in the "good guys"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In usage as at [bikede.org](http://www.bikede.org/2012/02/29/weve-got-the-goodies-final-winterfest-thursday-night-31/) ("We’ve Got the Goodies! Final Winterfest Recap") and at [blogs.esa.int atv](http://blogs.esa.int/atv/2011/02/26/got-the-goodies-from-atv/) ("Got the goodies from ATV. What, no pizza for me? I guess rehydrated macaroni & cheese will have to do...") *goodies* refers rather generally to "good stuff", as in things fun to have or good to eat.

The usual dictionary definitions of *goodies*, as for example, "good characters in a story, often a hero too" at [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/goodies), or "A candy, chocolate, praline, confection or sweetmeat" at [websters-dictionary-online](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/goodies), or "a thing that is very nice to eat" or "anything that is attractive and that people want to have" at [oxfordlearnersdictionaries](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/goody),  are largely irrelevant in answer to this question.  For that reason, I refer in following to [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com), which is not an authoritative source but in this case is indicative.

The majority of internet pages that mention *goodies* are likely to use the word as at [urbandictionary.com](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=goodies), as either a "slang term describing any one or more of 5 distinct parts of the female anatomy" or as "high grade marijuana, hydro, kush, headies". (For example, it seems to me that The Scabs' *Who got the goodies* [lyrics](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/s/scabs/who+got+the+goodies_20552543.html) are using the female anatomy sense.) However, the highest-voted answer on urbandictionary for the meaning of *goodies* is "whatever you want them to be, like your number, hugs, kisses etc."

Comment: Although the meaning is not explicit in OP's question I surmise that you have picked on the desired context... +1